# Debug Imported Files in VS Code

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I have recently set up the Java extension for VS Code.I have a folder that contains two files `Main.java` and `Person.java`. `Main.java` calls `Person.java`. When I set a breakpoint in `Main.java`, everything works as normal.However, when I set a breakpoint in `Person.java`, it just skips over it.

Are there any workarounds in this issue?

Main.java file

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        Person person = new Person();
        person.speak();
    }
}
```

Person.java file

```
public class Person {
    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("Speak!");
        //breakpoint on this line right here gets skipped
        System.out.println("Speak!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How you start debugging, and can you post the configuration in `launch.json` for me to reproduce your qeustion?

Answer (score 1):

Run -> Start Debugging, it stops at the breakpoint:

[image]